# Self manageable Memory mapped ByteBuffers

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files, mappedbytebuffer

My application has to buffer short living but quite big arrays of data. And there might be many big arrays at the same time in the memory.

I carrying files through the business logic in not ok. I have to manage these files and take care of `IOExceptions` every time.
I tried to apply `MappedByteBuffer` but it still requires manual managing of files, and especially deletion of used temporary files, because OS doesn't guarantee `/tmp` folder to be cleaned after my application.

Is there any box solution which provides a heap-like allocation of disk space and GC-like wiping of unused files?

Like MapDB but for byte buffers

Comment: Have you tested that just holding them in RAM as normal heap byte arrays won't work?

Comment: It works this way currently on a small amount of data, but I expect gigs of such data and don't want to increase memory on the instance